target = "_blank" redirects not working in ios webview mobile app
I have a a problem with a IOS webview mobile application. the stack is php and js. When the 'start' button is clicked, it redirects to the Rise 360 Articulate course in a new tab in Android and any other browsers except iOS. In iOS, the link opens in the same window because opening a new window is not working.
Here is the open tab code,
    if (isIOS) {
                    wnd = window.location.href = $(this).data("url");
                } else if (isWindows || isAndroid || isSafari || isChrome || isFirefox || isEdge || isOpera) {
                    wnd = window.open($(this).data("url"), 'Captivate Content', 'height=675,width=900,left=100');
                } else {
                    wnd = window.open($(this).data("url"),  'Captivate Content', 'height=675,width=900,left=100');
                }

Once inside the Articulate course, for both iOS and Android, there is an 'exit' module button. By default, in Rise 360 content, when closing Articulate, we can only add a URL to redirect. It has a default 'target="_blank"' attribute, which I cannot change from our code.
inside articulate code
<a class="blocks-button__button brand--ui" href="https://www.getsal.com/articulate_close.php" role="button" tabindex="0" target="_blank" style="background-color: rgb(40, 95, 159);">EXIT MODULE</a>

After clicking that, it goes to the PHP page, calls the TPL file, and using JavaScript, it closes the Articulate window.
 if (isAndroid ){
            window.location.href = 'comprehension.php?activity=' + activityId + '&site=' + site;
        }
        else if (isIOS){
            window.location.href = 'comprehension.php?activity=' + activityId + '&site=' + site;
        }
         else {
            window.close();
        }

It works fine in Android, but in iOS, when clicking the 'exit' button, nothing works. How can i fix that?
I tried different ways to close the tab in ios but nothing works. In ios that not redirect or open tab to close the articulate.

why is the code different for isIOS and isAndroid, etc?

Because, in IOS window.open method  isn't working
